# Setting a scrollbar to work with a treeview

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, tkinter-layout

I'm attempting to add a scrollbar to a tree here in order to keep the data within view for the user, as the tree stretches offscreen(the window is limited at 1280x720). However, the scrollbar does not move it across. Here is the code:

```
self.treeFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
    self.treeFrame.grid(row = 12,column = 0,columnspan = 1000,rowspan = 100)



    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.treeFrame,height = 100, columns = ('name','purchaseprice','previousprices','listingprice','buyingformat','postage','fees','potprofit','offers','viewcount','sold','offertaken','username','dispatch','delivered','returned','relist','feedback'))
    self.tree.heading('#0',text = 'saleID',anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('name',text = "Item Name",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('purchaseprice',text = "Purchase Price",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('previousprices',text = "Previous Prices",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('listingprice',text = "Listing Price", anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('buyingformat',text = "Buying Format",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('postage',text = "Postage",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('fees',text = "Fees",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('potprofit',text = "Potential Profit",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('offers',text = "Best Offer",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('viewcount',text = "Viewcount",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('sold',text = "Sold?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('offertaken',text = "Offer Taken?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('username',text = "Username",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('dispatch',text = "Dispatched?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('delivered',text = "Delivered?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('returned',text = "Returned?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('relist',text = "Relisted?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('feedback',text = "Feedback",anchor = 'w')

    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self,orient = "horizontal")
    self.tree.grid(row = 14,column = 0,sticky ='nsew')
    hsb.grid(row = 11,column = 0,columnspan = 10,sticky = 'ew')
    hsb.config(command = self.tree.xview)
```

Does anyone know how I would go about restricting the size of the tree in order to get it into a position where it can be scrolled across with in the bounds of the window?

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbars need to be told what command to run when the user moves the scrollbar, and widgets need to know which command to run when it has been scrolled. You're not doing either of these.

For example, in your code you need to do both of these:

```
hsb.configure(command=self.tree.xview)
self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
```